# How to properly pass a subset of fields from a TypeScript object in a method cleanly?

Tags: typescript

I often find myself needing to pass through a subset of fields from a large object in TypeScript. I will often use destructing to clean it up a bit, yet I don't love how duplicate the code appears even when it's not. Is there a better way I am missing?

```
interface MyLargerObject {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
  field3: string;
  field4: string;
  field5: string;
  field6: string;
  field7: string;
  field8: string;
  field9: string;
  otherField1: string;
  otherField2: string;
  otherField3: string;
  otherField4: string;
  otherField5: string;
}

interface MySmallerObject {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
  field3: string;
  field4: string;
  field5: string;
  otherField1: string;
  otherField2: string;
}

function subsetMethod(largerObject: MyLargerObject): MySmallerObject {
  const {
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4,
    field5
  } = largerObject;
  
  return {
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4,
    field5,
    otherField1: 'new1',
    otherField2: 123
  };
}
```

Additionally let's assume that there could be overlap between `MyLargerObject` and `MySmallerObject`. I would want to ensure that I don't overwrite overlapping fields for `MySmallerObject` with `largerObject` values in those cases.

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without undeclared types, so we can get to work on this in our own IDEs without having to clear up problems you're not asking about.

Comment: You can do the "opposite", use a spread parameter when destructuring and remove the fields you don't want. Or write a simple utility function for it.

Comment: @jcalz I didn't want to bloat the question with interface definitions, but I updated the question anyway. Hope that helps.

Comment: @super do you mean remove by setting the fields I don't want to undefined?

Comment: No. I mean `const {field6, field7, field8, field9, ...smallObject} = large`.

Comment: @super I don't really love that implementation since this method would need to be updated if any new fields are added to the larger object over time. It is also less confusing when reading the code since we would be referencing fields that are excluded from the result and not included. Thanks for the suggestion though I will keep it in mind.

Comment: You would probably want a helper `pick()` function around that copies just the props you name, and can use it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDJ3xW), but that only really pays for itself if you use it a bunch. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz I like that! I'm working on a sizable project and we may be doing this enough to justify that type of util function. Would you mind posting your sample code as an answer so I can accept it? I don't want to post it myself to take credit for your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to write this sort of code a lot, you could make a helper function like this:

```
function pick<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  const ret = {} as Pick<T, K>;
  for (const key of keys) { ret[key] = obj[key] }
  return ret;
}
```

The `pick()` function accepts an object `obj` of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T`, and a list of keys `keys`, where the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the elements of the list is generic type `K`.  The implementation copies all the named properties into a new object, which is returned and given the type [`Pick<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).

Note that I needed a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation, `const ret = {} as Pick<T, K>`, which isn't type safe (obviously an empty object is probably not of that type), but the plan is that by the time the function returns that assertion will be correct.

---

Armed with `pick()`, you can then call it on `largerObject` with the keys you care about, and then [spread it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) into your returned object literal so you can add any other properties you need:

```
function subsetMethod(largerObject: MyLargerObject): MySmallerObject {
  return {
    ...pick(largerObject, "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"),
    otherField1: "abc",
    otherField2: "def"
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AycoHNoDyARgFYQJjIDeAUMsjMBADYAmAjAFzIDOYUoXAG46DJmwBM3PgJDDRjFqwDM0-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-HkCWgyRB57h3V6IX0bdC8caEA)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to just spread the entire `largerObject` in the return object.

That is if your project is fully typed and you don't mind the extra memory usages as it deep copies the fields of `largerObject`.

```
interface MyLargerObject {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
  otherField1: string;
}

interface MySmallerObject {
  field1: string;
  otherField1: string;
}

function subsetMethod(largerObject: MyLargerObject): MySmallerObject {
   return {
     ...largerObject,
     otherField1: 'new1'
   };
}

const obj = subsetMethod({ field1: '1', field2: '2', otherField1: '3'})

obj.field1 // ok
obj.field2 // error
```